# looping through columns with putexcel command

Tags: stata

I have 8 different t-tests for the variable `lnDebt` for 8 consecutive years (variable `year` has years 2004-2011) by a `treatment` variable.

```
bysort year: ttest lnDebt, by(treatment)
```

Using `putexcel`, I try to get a table with 8 columns (2004 2005 ... 2011) and 3 rows (Low debt mean, High debt mean, p-value diff. in means). However, I can not make it loop through the 8 different years (columns). The code I got so far is:

```
local row=5                          /*I want to start the table in row 5*/
local ncol=2                         /*I want to start the table in column B*/
local col: word `ncol' of `c(ALPHA)' /*Preparing the loop through columns B to I*/
levelsof year, local(years)
foreach y of local years {
qui ttest lnDebt1 if year==`y', by(treatment)
putexcel `col'5=(r(mu_1))
putexcel `col'6=(r(mu_2))
putexcel `col'7=(r(p))
local ++ncol
}
```

I don't know why, but it only reports the last year statistics (2011) in column B. I would like, year 2004 statistics in column B, 2005 statistics in column C, 2006 statistics in column D, etc. etc. until 2011 statistics in column I.

Any idea of how to make my desired table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug in your code is that you never update the local macro `col`. `col` is defined just once. When you define `col` it doesn't ever know, and certainly does not  remember, that it was defined in terms of the current `ncol`. It's not a pointer, therefore.

Hence each time around your loop, you just overwrite column B with the latest result so far.

This doesn't appear to be complete code even within context, as e.g. you never refer to `row` after defining it.

```
local row = 5                          /* start the table in row 5*/
local ncol = 2                         /* start the table in column B*/

levelsof year, local(years)
foreach y of local years {
    qui ttest lnDebt1 if year ==`y', by(treatment)
    local col : word `ncol' of `c(ALPHA)'
    putexcel `col'5 = (r(mu_1))
    putexcel `col'6 = (r(mu_2))
    putexcel `col'7 = (r(p))
    local ++ncol
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nick. You're right with the "local row" command. This is a result of trying a bunch of things before posting it here. I do not definitely need it in this version of the code. Thanks again!